How to set a Cyrilic font for a single chapter
I am writing a book in English, with one chapter (summary) in French and one in Russian. There are no problems with the French one, but I am struggling with the fonts for the Russian chapter.
The style file is a local (but not mine) homebrew and I am not sure what exactly is happening inside. As far as I understand, it loads lmodern and uses phv font family for chapter headers because I see the following lines there:
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\RequirePackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % For pdfTeX we must use old 8-bit font technologies
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\newcommand*{\selectfontchapheads}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont} 

For my chapter, I use
\selectlanguage{russian}
\chapter*{Реферат} \label{ch:sum_ru}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:sum_ru}}
\chaptermark{Реферат}

\subsection*{Введение}
Очень \textbf{важная} проблема

\selectlanguage{english}

It compiles but there is no bold font and I have the following warnings:
main.aux: warning: 39: Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead
main.toc: warning: 9: Font shape `T2A/lmr/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `T2A/lmr/m/n' instead
summary_ru.tex: warning: 3: Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/sc' undefined(Font) using `T2A/lmr/m/n' instead
summary_ru.tex: warning: 3: Font shape `T2A/phv/m/sc' undefined(Font) using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead
summary_ru.tex: warning: 3: Font shape `T2A/phv/b/sc' undefined(Font) using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead
summary_ru.tex: warning: 44: Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/it' undefined(Font) using `T2A/lmr/m/n' instead

What I need is to set a Times New Roman Cyrillic font with bold and italics for this particular chapter. How can it be done?

I cannot help with the headers, because you don't say how you produce them

lmodern has no support for Cyrillic. You can choose the standard cmr family for it.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{nameref}% or hyperref

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for smaller pictures

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{English}

This text is in English.

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}
\chapter*{Реферат} \label{ch:sum_ru}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:sum_ru}}
\chaptermark{Реферат}

\subsection*{Введение}
Очень \textbf{важная} проблема
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot! It partially works, but there are two things that I prefer to post as separate comments to simplify the discussion.


I have the warning "No file T2Almr.fd." I tried to google for it, but no conclusive result so far.



I also had the warning Font shape T2A/phv/m/sc undefined(Font) using T2A/cmr/m/n instead where, as far as I understand, the phv font is used for chapter headers. Thus, I tried adding \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{phv}{cmr}. Unfortunately, I got the error No declaration for shape T2A/cmr/b/sc. \chapter*{Реферат}. I understand it as there is no Cyrillic Bold SmallCaps for the CMR fonts. Is that right? What can be another font, or how to force the particular chapter header not to be SmallCaps?


@Arastas Of course you get the warning, but unless you present a full compilable example showing the issue, nobody can help.

Thanks for your help. I have started a new, more specific question with an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/725443/how-to-deal-with-bold-small-caps-cyrilic-in-chapter-headers
