How to deal with Bold Small Caps Cyrilic in chapter headers?
I am writing a book using a local style file based on the report class. The style uses lmr for the main text and phv for the headers. It works just fine until I have to include one chapter in Russian; see the example below. To deal with the main text, I use \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}, and it works. However, when I try to do the same for the headers via \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{phv}{cmr} I get the error No declaration for shape T2A/cmr/b/sc. \chapter*{Реферат}. As far as I understand, it is due to the \scshape and \bfseries in the chapter headers in the style file.

Is there any font that supports bold small caps Cyrillic?
If not, how can I change one particular chapter header style to avoid the small caps?
Or am I misunderstanding something, and the problem comes from a different place?
Also, I have the warning No file T2Almr.fd. - how to fix that?

The minimum example:
\pdfminorversion=7 

% --- This section comes from the style file that I should follow as close as possible
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % For pdfTeX we must use old 8-bit font technologies
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[russian,french,english]{babel} % Last language is the default, use \selectlanguage{english} to switch
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Afin de r\'{e}aliser soi-même les en-têtes et pieds de page, voir chaque d\'{e}but de chapitre.

\newcommand*{\selectfontchapheads}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont} % Font style used chapter headings

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-30\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \selectfontchapheads \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 50\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \selectfontchapheads \Huge \bfseries #1 \par\nobreak
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}

% --- Here come my packages and commands
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for smaller pictures
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}
%\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{phv}{cmr}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
This is \textbf{English} \textsc{Introduction}.

\selectlanguage{russian}
\chapter*{Реферат}
А это \textbf{русский} \textsc{реферат}.
\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter{First Chapter}
This is \textbf{First} \textsc{Chapter}.

    
\end{document}



If the substitution for phv is commented, I have the results as given below; note that the Russian chapter header does not follow the style of the English one. I also receive the warnings Font shape T2A/phv/m/sc undefined(Font) using T2A/cmr/m/n instead and Font shape T2A/phv/b/sc undefined(Font) using T2A/cmr/m/n instead.
If I uncomment the substitution for phv, I have the error No declaration for shape T2A/cmr/b/sc. \chapter*{Реферат}.



If you compile with a Unicode-aware engine like xelatex or lualatex, then you can use (appropriate) open type fonts and font setup is simpler: \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{NotoSerif} \setsansfont{NotoSans}.

@Cicada No, unfortunately, the source should be pdflatex compatible.

Non-legacy font output can be included in pdfLaTeX documents as image or .pdf files,

You need a sans serif font that, besides supporting Cyrillic (more precisely, the T2A encoding), has small caps.
There aren't many, I'm afraid, actually one, namely Ysabeau
In all cases, change the definition of \selectfontchapheads into
\newcommand*{\selectfontchapheads}{\sffamily}% Font style used chapter headings

With \usepackage{ysabeau} you get

In my opinion you should not use Helvetica for chapter headers in the English part and Ysabeau (the only choice) for the Russian part. Anyway, it's possible to accomplish the task.
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % unneeded
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % For pdfTeX we must use old 8-bit font technologies
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{fix-cm} % irrelevant
\usepackage[russian,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% --- Here come my packages and commands

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for smaller pictures
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newcommand*{\selectfontchapheads}{\sffamily}% Font style used chapter headings

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-30\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \selectfontchapheads \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 50\p@
}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \reset@font
        \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \selectfontchapheads \Huge \bfseries #1 \par\nobreak
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 30\p@
}}


\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{lmr}{cmr}
\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{phv}{Ysabeau-TLF}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
This is \textbf{English} \textsc{Introduction}.

\selectlanguage{russian}
\chapter*{Реферат}
А это \textbf{русский} \textsc{реферат}.
\selectlanguage{english}

\chapter{First Chapter}
This is \textbf{First} \textsc{Chapter}.

    
\end{document}



Thanks! Unfortunately, it also changes the style of English chapter headers, especially for 'R.' Is there a way to apply this change only to the Russian chapter?

@Arastas I'm not sure what you mean…

When I look at the attached images, I see that R in the 'Introduction' in my pictures differs from yours; the same goes for R in 'First' and 'Chapter'.
However, when I try to add \usepackage{ysabeau} and \newcommand*{\selectfontchapheads}{\sffamily} in my example, the compilation fails without any error in the log. I'm confused. It's MikTeX, if that matters.

@Arastas Of course it does: the font is Ysabeau in every case. I don't think you want different fonts. If you really want Helvetica, you're out of luck with pdflatex. About “compilation failing with no error in the log”, I don't know what to say.

I would like to have the original font for all English chapters and change it only for the Russian one.

@Arastas I added the requested way. But, please, don't: documents should not be a font patchwork.

Oh, I see your point, and I agree. However, the example does not compile for me. I get the error !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file a_nql2ou.enc): cannot open encoding file for reading  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

@Arastas You seem to have a bad installation of ysabeau.

For those with the same problem, I just copied the .enc file directly into the project folder, and it works.

@Arastas Or, likely with MIKTeX, you have to rebuild the font maps.
